# Action/character of group representation on dual space

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am somewhat confused how trace is defined on the induced action of a group representation on the dual space. In my case, I think of the action as $u^\star \to u^\star \circ \rho(g^{-1})$ for representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$. To me, defining the character as ${\rm trace}{\rho(g^{-1})}$ does not clearly show that this definition is consistent with finding out what the action of $\rho(g^{-1})$ does if you view $u^\star$ as a vector of coefficients of the element as a linear combination of dual space basis elements and thinking of the action of the group as acting on such a vector by multiplication on the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick a basis for $V$ and a dual basis for the dual space $V^{\ast}$, then $\rho(g)$ can be considered matrix-valued, and you will find that the matrix of $g$'s action on the dual space is in fact $\rho^\ast(g):=\rho(g^{-1})^T$. This has the same diagonal entries as $\rho(g^{-1})$, so the traces $\mathrm{tr}\rho^\ast(g)=\mathrm{tr}\rho(g^{-1})$ are the same.